# What's causing the drop today?

Tags: economic-theory

The BTC/USD is down 10.38% at the moment. 
Does anyone know what happend?

Comment: Please read the [FAQ](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). This type of question is not appropriate for this site.

Answer (score 2):

Individuals playing Bitcoin for short-term investment make decisions based on history and round numbers. When you stack up some Bitcoin and they appreciate in value, you need to decide when to dump your Bitcoin for dollars before the value goes back down.

For many shorting Bitcoin, $200 was the magical number established back in April. When these people sell on the same day, then we have a lot of demand for Bitcoin satisfied and prices down.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a correction. It happens sooner or later.

Answer (score -1):

someone sold a lot, causing a panic probably.
but it is up 50% in ten days, so nothing to worry about :)

Comment: how do you know that?

Comment: 50% up in 10 days sounds pretty worrying to me.